# How to remove unwanted lines in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, polygons

When I run the following code:

```
Graphics3D[{{EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Red, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 
      0}}]}, {EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Red, 
   Polygon[{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 
      0}}]}, {EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}], Green, 
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}]}}, 
 ViewPoint -> {-2, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

I get unwanted "tick marks," for lack of a better term, on the bottom of the green polygon, only when viewed at certain angles though.  I don't know why they're there in the first place since I haven't messed with the opacity and they only show up where the polygons meet.  MY QUESTION is how do I remove those marks while still having a thick edge for each polygon?

Also, I know that I could just use `Rectangle[]` if I wanted to make the plot above without the marks, but my question is for `Polygon[]`.  Thanks

Comment: seems to be related to [Unintended edge extensions in 3D Cube rendering](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15735/125) and [Opacity renders lines incorrect in certain viewing angles](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65260/125). Try if [Simon's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65263/125) or [halirutan's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29469/125) gets rid of the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I followed the instructions from the first link and it works fine now.  Edit ->Preferences -> Advanced -> Option Inspector -> Graphics Options -> BSPTree