# A possible bug when overlaying objects with zero Opacity

Tags: graphics3d, opacity, free-wolfram-engine

I believe I have discovered a bug in WolframScript but it's *a priori* more probable that I'm doing something wrong so I'd be grateful if someone either confirmed the problem, tells me what I'm doing wrong, or tell me a way around it. I am using WolframScript, version 1.10.0 on a laptop.

I was writing code to display an evolving lattice of spheres and did this by collecting all the spheres and manipulating their opacity as time increased but there were anomalies in the result. The code below is a minimal example. Basically, it comprises

- a fully visible sphere,
- an invisible one that partially occludes the first,
- two invisible spheres which are closer to the observer and so appear bigger than the others and they each totally eclipse both of the first two.
- a fifth invisible sphere that partially eclipses the first two

With only two eclipsing invisible spheres everything appears as I would expect (foo.png) but when I add a third then the overlap becomes invisible (bar.png), as if the fifth sphere renders the opacity of the combination as zero and the background is visible. This isn't the full story though, and I gave up trying to diagnose what was going on, because if I increase the size of the fifth sphere then the combination (baz.png) is downright weird.

```
sph = {
       Blue,
       Sphere[{51, 1, 1}, Sqrt[2]],
       Red,
       Opacity[0.],
       Sphere[{51 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), 1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3])}, Sqrt[2]],
       Orange,
       Opacity[0.0],
       Sphere[{49 + 4*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 4*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), 1 + 2*(-1 - Sqrt[2/3]) + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3])}, 4],
       Sphere[{51 + 4*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), 1 + 4*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), 1 + 2*(-1 - Sqrt[2/3]) + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3])}, 4]
}
sph5 = Sphere[{49 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3])},Sqrt[2]];
sph6 = Sphere[{49 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3]), -1 + 2*(1 + Sqrt[2/3])},2];

ShowSpheres[sph_,filename_] := Module[{},
  t = 0.705;
  gr = Graphics3D[ sph,
           ViewPoint->{1*Cos[t],1*Sin[t],0},
           ViewVertical->{0,0,1},
           ViewAngle -> Pi/4,
           Boxed -> False,
           Background -> LightBlue
         ];
         Export[filename,gr]]

ShowSpheres[sph, "/tmp/foo.png"]
ShowSpheres[Join[sph,{Opacity[0.],Green,sph5}], "/tmp/bar.png"]
ShowSpheres[Join[sph,{Opacity[0.],Green,sph6}], "/tmp/baz.png"]
```

[image: foo.png is what I expected]

[image: bar.png is unexpected, adding a fifth, invisible, sphere turns some of the blue sphere transparent]

[image: baz.png is weird, the fifth sphere has been expanded but I don't understand what effect it has had]

Edit: This is not the same question [as asked here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274597/multiple-opaque-objects-occlude-lines-when-they-shouldnt) although it has the same answer. The question at reference asked why objects were occluded when they shouldn't. This question was about the opposite, objects were made invisible but shouldn't be and the background shone through.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Does this answer your question? [Multiple opaque objects occlude lines when they shouldn't](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274597/multiple-opaque-objects-occlude-lines-when-they-shouldnt) There are two solutions mentioned in the answer, which seem to work.

Comment: @Damien, thanks for the reference. No, it doesn't, though I see the similarity in the problems.

Comment: Are you sure? Please look at [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPdoc.png). I've marked the additional option with red.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake, I was putting the rendering options in theGraphicsD call. Everything is Ok now